# SQL Server : how can I increment an int based on the primary key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sequence, primary-key, identity

I have two tables, `cinema` and `theater`, and I want the theater to be unique based on the `cinema`. So I wrote this:

```
create table cinema
(
    mID int identity primary key
)

create table theater
(
    tID int identity,
    mID int foreign key references cinema(cID),
    primary key (tID,cID)
)
```

Although this works as I want on the cinema table, this will create a new tID only based on the tID, and not based on the primary key. Is there a way that I can increment the tID based on the other theaters I added to that cinema?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167974/discussion-on-question-by-daskdadi-sql-server-how-can-i-increment-an-int-based).

Answer (score -2):

There isn't any built-in support for what you're trying to do in SQL Server. But you can get the same effect using code. It's just a matter of where you want to put it.

Option 1: Create a Trigger that calculates the new value for tID. (This can be ORM friendly.)

Option 2: Create a Stored Procedure and do not grant your application permissions to insert records or modify that column.

Option 3: Handle everything client-side using a transaction. (I don't recommend this as it is the slowest and most intrusive way to do it, but it's very common.)

Option 4: Don't do it and instead calculate a separate TheaterNumber using RowNumer in a view. The downside here is that it isn't stable and can be changed if a theater is deleted.

Comment: What's with all of the down-votes? Any of those options will work and I've used them all at various times.

Answer (score -2):

By the sounds of it, 1 movie can be played at multiple theaters and 1 theater can play multiple movies. If this is correct, then you have a many-to-many relationship, which will require an intersection table.

```
CREATE TABLE Movie
(
    MovieKey INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
)

CREATE TABLE Theater
(
    TheaterKey INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
)

CREATE TABLE MovieTheaterMap
(
    MovieKey FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Movie(MovieKey)
    TheaterKey FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Theater(TheaterKey)
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (MovieKey ASC, TheaterKey ASC)
)
```

Also, once you create the three tables above, you can then create a view to sit on top of the three tables so that you can see all of the relevant information.

Comment: You misunderstood the question entirely. There are N cinemas. We'll call them A, B, C, etc. There are M theaters. We'll call them A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, C1, C2, C3. As you can see, there are multiple theater #1's, each being unique to a cinema.

Comment: Lol, you just validated my answer. Movie table will be A, B, C. Theater table will be 1, 2, 3. The MovieTheaterMap will be: A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3, C1, C2, C3.

Comment: No, a cinema can have multiple theaters (not movies), but a theater can only have one cinema.

Comment: I see - the cinema is the building that stores all of the theaters, along with concessions and what not. Are the theaters unique to each cinema? or, can they be non-unique, and classified by type (e.g., regular, DBOX, lounge seating, IMAX, XD, etc.)?